# Using linear mixed models to compare two groups of patients with grouped measurements

Tags: mixed-model

**Data description**

I have a data set consisting of multiple measurements of different molecules (cytokines) in 72 patients. In each patient, we measured the concentration of 50 different cytokines (so the total data set consists of 72 x 50 measurements). In addition, other information about these patients was collected, among which the ASIA score (this metric is used to assess the impairment of a patient). We grouped the patients into two categories (ABC vs DE), based on the ASIA score. The table below shows how the data looks like. Note that this is only a subset of 5 cytokines (instead of 50), hence there are 72 x 5 = 360 measurements shown here.

|  | patient | ASIA_score | cytokine | concentration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1-056 | ABC | IL-2 | -0.175060 |
| 1 | 1-067 | ABC | IL-2 | 0.702305 |
| 2 | 1-071 | ABC | IL-2 | 0.015395 |
| 3 | 1-107 | ABC | IL-2 | -0.768012 |
| 4 | 1-109 | ABC | IL-2 | -0.516611 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 355 | 2-106 | DE | IFN-gamma | -0.277945 |
| 356 | 2-131 | DE | IFN-gamma | -0.277945 |
| 357 | 2-173 | DE | IFN-gamma | -0.256971 |
| 358 | 2-179 | DE | IFN-gamma | -0.277945 |
| 359 | 2-193 | DE | IFN-gamma | -0.277945 |

**Question**

We want to test whether there is a difference in cytokine expression (concentration) between the two groups (ABC vs DE). Since the variables are clustered (different cytokines), I was thinking of using a linear mixed model design. Would this be an appropriate way to answer my research question? If so, what would be the best way to design this model?

The figure below illustrates the comparison I aim to make. Here, each data point represents a measurement of the cytokine concentration in a patient belonging to either group ABC or DE. The points are colored according to which cytokine was measured. We want to compare the patients with ASIA_score ABC versus patients with ASIA_score DE.
[image]

Comment: can you explain how does this differ from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/591777/how-do-i-compare-two-groups-with-nested-variables ?

Comment: It's the same question, but I tried to explain it more clearly right now. I want to compare the two groups of patients (72 in total). Here I show an example for 5 cytokines (72 x 5 = 360 measurements in total). As can be seen in the figure, the measurements are grouped per cytokine, so I want to take this into account when comparing the two groups, instead of performing a simple Wilcoxon test.

Comment: No answer was provided in that thread.

Comment: please, have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Don't understand me wrong here, I don't want to be offensive, but this comment is not very helpful sorry.